# How Can I Show Web Page On Augmented Reality?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm developing augmented reality with unity game engine.
I can instantiate 3d model and audio and etc.

So i want to show web page(Html5) on AR, i purchase  [uniwebview](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/uniwebview-3-92605) plugin to show web page on android or iOS, but how can i show on AR space?

Comment: You first need to make sure this would be supported, best is to contact the UniWebView dev. Then if so, displaying a web view is just like displaying an image.

Comment: @Everts , After all, uniwebview don't support this, but is it possible to show web page in AR?

Comment: I would say that Unity does not support it. So you'd have to find an asset like UniWebView that does support AR/VR, maybe this https://github.com/vuplex/ar-foundation-webview-example